# Jquery: Enter to blur

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7wp9rs2s/ this is how far I have come with this project.

Basically, in the above fiddle you can double click on one of the 4 items and when you do, you get a textbox where you can edit it. Then you click out and it goes back to being a text. Most users wont click out but will instead press enter (like SO's comment function) so if the user presses enter, while making the edit, I want the script to react in the same way as if the user clicked out of the box.

I know how to capture the Enter key:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    alert("in Enter");
  }
});
```

But I do not know how to make the function do what I need :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions are called on blur, so simply trigger a blur on the input :

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    $(e.target).blur();
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7wp9rs2s/1/)

Comment: Gah! I feel like a twit now... it took you all of 2 seconds to solve this! It took me 5 mins to even write the explanation for the question...

Comment: @Ryan, Once you know it, you'll never forget it. If that 5 min taught you something, it is not a waste of time ;)

Comment: As you might have guessed, I am a JQ noob, SO won't let me select your answer for another 7 mins... thanks for the help!

Comment: Hey again, quick question but won't that Enter function fire everytime someone presses the enter key even if they are not in that "editing textbox" that pops up?

Comment: @Ryan indeed it will, but you can also use `$('.editINPUT').keypress()` to solve that issue. Or you could also check if `e.target` is `editINPUT`.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I'll start reading up on how to do that :) - I may have to bother you again if the squirrels in my head don't find the nut :P